# Android N how to deny layout scaled when system screen zoom / display size change

Tags: android, android-layout

My App has some complex layouts that hope not to be scaled in "Large" display size of Android N.

I just thought a stupid method to calculate the suitable scale ratio by screen density, iterate each view of layout, and reset the LayoutParameters for each view.

My question is, this is a common issue/requirement for develop, is there any api or layout setting to deny the "display size" change in those layouts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the doc is not updated yet on that. It's possible find a description of this new functionality here ([Screen Zoom](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#screen-zoom)), but there's no way to know how not support it.

You can decide to handling the configuration change by yourself adding some parameters to your configChanges. There is a "secret" value "density" not yet in the doc but works as expected. Just add this line in the manifest to your activity.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="density"/>
```

I suggest to use also these if you want to manage by yourself the Multi-WIndow mode. So your code could be better like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation|density"/>
```

Comment: its completely messing up my recyclerview with a gridlayout manager. i have a row of 3 elements, spacing between each element. but when i change over to the largest "display size" the elements are overlapping.