# Changing 'Screen Zoom' setting to 'Large' completely messing few screens (especially fragment layout) in my App

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

We know 'Android-N (7.0)' has introduced new feature where we can change 'Screen-Zoom' level from device settings. But changing 'Screen Zoom' level to 'Large' completely messing few screens  (especially fragment layout) in my app. As suggested [here,](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes#screen-zoom) I have specified dimensions with **Density-independent Pixel** (dp), also I tried solutions given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283939/android-n-how-to-deny-layout-scaled-when-system-screen-zoom-display-size-chang) but, unfortunately none of this worked for me. Please let me know if you have any solution to this problem OR if there is any way we can ignore 'Screen Zoom' setting effect particularly for our app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this [third-party library](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) and it resolved almost 85% problem.